# Spark: How to normalize all the columns of DataFrame effectively?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to normalize all the columns of `DataFrame`. I use the following method.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import stddev_pop, avg, broadcast, mean, stddev
def normalize(df, columns, select_col=[]):
    aggMean = []
    aggStd = []
    for column in columns:
        aggMean.append(mean(df[column]).alias(column))
        aggStd.append(stddev_pop(df[column]).alias(column))
    averages = df.agg(*aggMean).collect()[0]
    stds = df.agg(*aggStd).collect()[0]
    for column in columns:
        df = df.withColumn(column + "_norm", ((df[column] - averages[column]) / stds[column]))
        select_col.append(column + "_norm")
    df = df.select(select_col)
    return df
normalize(train_df,train_df.columns)
```

However, it's too slow when the `DataFrame` has about `10,000` columns. What's the best way to normalize such DataFrame.

For convenience to discuss, I give an example of `DataFrame`,

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)],
["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use the MinMax scaler in spark ml :
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=minmaxscaler#pyspark.ml.feature.MinMaxScaler
So, you have to convert your columns into a vector, minmax scale it,convert it into an array and if needed back to seperate columns

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline,PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler,MinMaxScaler
from pyspark.sql.types import *
#%%
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)],schema=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"])
vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=df.columns, outputCol="features",handleInvalid='skip')
normalizer = MinMaxScaler(inputCol="features", outputCol="scaledFeatures",min=0,max=1)
pipeline_normalize = Pipeline(stages=[vecAssembler,normalizer])
df_transf = pipeline_normalize.fit(df).transform(df)
#%%
to_array = F.udf(lambda x: (x.toArray().tolist()), ArrayType(DoubleType())) # IF spark 3.0.0 then a api - vectortoarray available
df_array = df_transf.withColumn("scaledFeatures",to_array("scaledFeatures"))
#%%\
df_final= df_array.select([F.col('scaledFeatures')[i].alias(df.columns[i]) for i in range(len(df.columns))])
```

Note : this is a scaler and not a normalizer. If you want it as per in your formula,then use : http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=minmaxscaler#pyspark.ml.feature.StandardScaler instead of minmaxscaler

Comment: Can it transform all the columns in the same time?

Comment: A small question, how to solve `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'handleInvalid'` in spark `2.3.2`

Comment: are you importing from mlib?

Comment: I use spark 2.4.0 . Looks like in spark 2.3.0 handleInvalid is not available. Check the api documentation for 2.3.0 - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#module-pyspark.ml.feature

Comment: @Raghu Hi, I have a question. When handleInavlid = skip or keep, min max scaler ignore all Null values when calculating min, max values, right?

Comment: @haneulkim - Hi, as I last remember, having handle valid as keep and using minmax scaler threw me a error. Is this updated now? I can give a try and let you know